# Finding real $a$, $b$, $c$ such that $x^5 - 2x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 - 2x + c$ has $1+i$ as a zero, and one negative integer as a zero with multiplicity $2$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

> Find $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$, if one zero of $p$ is $1+i$ and $p$ has one negative integer zero with multiplicity $2$, where: 
>   $$p(x) = x^5 - 2x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 - 2x + c$$

I know that one zero of $p$ is $1-i$, so I can reduce it one degree down after dividing with $x-2$, but after that I'm stuck.

I tried using Vieta's formulas, but with no result.

Comment: You're mistaken to use $(x-2)$ as a factor.  Instead, it should be $(x-q)^2$ for some unknown $0 < q \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You have to divide by $(x-1-i)(x-1+i)$, not $x-2$.

Comment: @onion:  No.  $p(x) = (x - (1+i))(x-q)^2 r(x)$ where $r(x)$ is a quadratic.  "Multiplicity $2$" means you have two roots that are the same... *not* that the *value* has anything to do with $2$.  Your revision:  again NO.  The multiplicity-2 root is *different* from the root at $1 + i$.  Please read carefully.

Comment: Oh right, i missed that. I'll try fixing it now.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork You can always divide out both known complex roots to reduce the degree by two! That's *before* discussing the rest of the roots (where the multiplicity information is used).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all coefficients are reals, $p$ is divisible by $$(x-1+i)(x-1-i)=(x-1)^2+1=x^2-2x+2.$$

We have $$p(x)=x^5-2x^4+ax^3+bx^2-2x+c=$$
$$=x^5-2x^4+2x^3+(a-2)x^3-2(a-2)x^2+2(a-2)x+(b+2a-4)x^2-(2a-2)x+c=$$
$$=(x^2-2x+2)(x^3+(a-2)x)+(b+2a-4)x^2-(2a-2)x+c.$$
We need $$b+2a-4=k,$$ $$2a-2=2k$$ and $$c=2k,$$ which gives
$$b=3-a,$$ $$c=2a-2$$ and
$$p(x)=(x^2-2x+2)((x^3-2x-1+a(x+1)).$$
Now, let $x^3-2x-1+a(x+1)=q(x).$

Thus, $q$ and $q'$ have the same negative integer root.

$$q'(x)=3x^2-2+a,$$ which gives $$a=2-3x^2.$$

Id est, for the same root we obtain the following equation.
$$x^3-2x-1+(2-3x^2)(x+1)=0$$ or
$$2x^3+3x^2-1=0$$ or
$$2x^3+4x^2+2x-x^2-2x-1=0$$ or
$$(x+1)^2(2x-1)=0,$$
which gives $x=-1$ and $a=-1$.

Comment: I have root of derivative of $q$ in terms of $a$, so now I  plug that in in $q$ ?
Or you've done it somehow faster .. ?

Comment: Just, $3x^2-2+a=0$, which gives $2x^3+3x^2-1=0$ and from here $x=-1$.

Comment: Can you please explain that, I don't follow how from $3x^2 -2 +a =0$ you derived $2x^3 +3x^2 -1=0$ ?

Comment: @someone I added something. See now.

Answer (score 1):

$$x_1=1+i$$
$$x_2=1-i$$
$$x_3=x_4 = m<0$$
and $$x_5=k$$ then we have $$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=2$$

$$2+2m+k=2\implies \boxed{k=-2m}$$
and $$x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5({1\over x_1}+{1\over x_2}+{1\over x_3}+{1\over x_4}+{1\over x_5}) =-2$$

so $$\boxed{2m^2k(1+{2\over m}+{1\over k})=-2}\implies m^2(2m+3)=-1$$

Since $m^2\mid -1$ we have $m^2=1\implies m=-1$ and $k=2$.

The rest should be easy now.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork If we know $p$ has one complex zero $z$, then $z$ conjugate is also zero, if $p$ is with real coefficients (if you are talking about that)

Answer (score 0):

If $ 1 + i $ is the root of the polynomial 
$$
p(x) = x^5 - 2x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 - 2x + c
$$
and  $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ then $1-i$ is root of $p(x)$. Soon $q(x)=(x-1+i)\cdot(x-1-i)=(x^2-2x+2)$ divide $p(x)$ and 
\begin{align}
x^5 - 2x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 - 2x + c
=&
(x^2-2x+2)\big( x^3 -(2r+s)x^2+(r^2+2rs)x-r^2s\big)
\\
=&x^5
\\
&\hspace{0.5cm} -2x^4-(2r+s)x^4
\\
&\hspace{1.0cm}  +2x^3+2(2r+s)x^3+(r^2+2rs)x^3
\\
&\hspace{1.5cm}  -2(2r+s)x^2-2(r^2+2rs)x^2-r^2sx^2
\\
&\hspace{2.0cm}  +2(r^2+2rs)x+2r^2sx
\\
&\hspace{2.5cm}  +2(r^2+2rs)x+2r^2sx
\\
&\hspace{3.0cm}  -2r^2s
\end{align}
Note that 
\begin{align}
-2-(2r+s)=&-2\quad \implies \quad 2r+s=0\\
+2+2(2r+s)+(r^2+2rs)=&a\\
-2(2r+s)-2(r^2+2rs)-r^2s=&b\\
+2(r^2+2rs)+2r^2s=&-2 \quad \implies \quad 2r^2+4rs+2r^2s=-2\\
-2r^2s=&c\\
\end{align}